# Given that $x+y+z=30,$ show that the number of possible arrangements is the largest for $x=y=z=10$.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

> Question: $x$ red balls, $y$ black balls and $z$ white balls are to be arranged in a row. Suppose that any two balls of the same colour are indistinguishable. Given that $x+y+z=30,$ show that the number of possible arrangements is the largest for $x=y=z=10$.

My approach: Number of ways to place the $x$ indistinguishable red balls in a row is the same as choosing $x$ places out of the $30$ places, and is equal to $\binom{30}{x}$.

Now, we place the $y$ black balls. We have already placed the $x$ red balls, therefore there are $30-x$ places left for the black balls to be placed. Therefore, the black balls can be placed in $\binom{30-x}{y}$ ways.

The remaining $30-(x+y)=z$ places will be filled by $z$ indistinguishable white balls in $\binom{z}{z}=1$ way.

Now, by the rule of product the total number of possible arrangements=$\dbinom{30}{x}\dbinom{30-x}{y}$.

Therefore, the problem simply asks to find the condition under which the term $\dbinom{30}{x}\dbinom{30-x}{y}$ attains its maximum value. I was trying to apply AM-GM inequality and deduce the same, but I didn't get anything significant.

Hints please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the number of arrangements as $\frac {30!}{x!y!z!}$ so you want to minimize $x!y!z!$.  Assume $x \ge y \ge z$.  Note that if $x \neq z, x \ge z+2$.  Then $x!z! \gt (x-1)!(z+1)!$ and you get a smaller value by decreasing $x$ and increasing $z$.  This process terminates when $x=y=z$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the total number of possible arrangements can be written as $N(x,y,z) = \frac{30!}{x!y!z!}$.  Now, consider the ratio
$$
\frac{N(x+1,y-1,z)}{N(x,y,z)} = \frac{y}{x+1}.
$$